# Getting Error: 'mat-date-range-picker-actions' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-daterangepicker

I want to add action buttons in my material date range picker. So i added this code given in documentation on link below

Documentation link: [Date picker actions](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#confirmation-action-buttons)

```
<mat-date-range-picker #picker [touchUi]="true"> <mat-date-range-picker-actions> <button mat-button matDateRangePickerCancel>Cancel</button> <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matDateRangePickerApply> Apply </button> </mat-date-range-picker-actions> </mat-date-range-picker>
```

But when i run application i am getting error: `'mat-date-range-picker-actions' is not a known element`

I have also imported `MatDatepickerModule` and `MatNativeDateModule` still getting this error. Without action buttons it is working fine,

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: @OwenKelvin Yes. Getting same issue even after restarting server.

Answer (score 3):

Got it working after updating Angular material version. Since `date-picker-action-buttons` were added in version 11.1.0 and i was using version `10.2.2`

It working after updating material version using these commands

```
npm install @angular/cdk@latest
npm install @angular/material@latest
npm install @angular/material-moment-adapter@latest
```

Comment: What is the last line for?